# "Multiple Displays" dropdown box menu missing

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, acer-aspire

wish you could help me. i just purchased a new ACER desktop with an extra monitor.  Tried to change  the "multiple displays" setting to extended displays but it the dropdown box menu is missing. I am using Windows 10 home single language

Comment: Generally, Windows does not show multi-monitor dialogues unless an external monitor is both plugged in and enabled. On a laptop this is usually done with a function key, but on a desktop it is normally a BIOS setting. It's possible that your graphics output duplicates the same image on all the connectors, in which case you'll need a separate graphics card for the second monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Intel HD Graphics driver. When i tried to uninstall, it didn't work, so try to just disable that driver and use only the NVIDIA driver.

[image]